# OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.AuthorizationCodeReceived event not firing

Tags: azure-active-directory

using this sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

This works as expected when running it locally
But when we deploy it (azure web app), it still authenticates, but the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.AuthorizationCodeReceived event is not firing.

This the code.

```
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        });


private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
{
    var code = context.Code;

    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
    string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

    Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, graphResourceId);
}
```

This is a problem because it requires caching of the token to make an outbound call.
Since it doesn’t have it, it throws.

There was an issue that caused this related to a trailing slash after the redir url but we’ve already tried that.

So two questions…
1)  Under what conditions would event get fired and why would this work when running locally? According to the docs it should be "Invoked after security token validation if an authorization code is present in the protocol message."
2)  What is the best way to debug this?  Not clear on what to look for here.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Under what conditions would event get fired and why would this work when running locally? According to the docs it should be "Invoked after security token validation if an authorization code is present in the protocol message."

As the document point, this event will fire when the web app verify the  authorization code is present in the protocol message.

> 2) What is the best way to debug this? Not clear on what to look for here.

There are many reason may cause the exception when you call the request with the access_token. For example, based on the code you were using the `NaiveSessionCache` which persist the token using the `Sesstion` object. It means that you may also get the exception when you deploy the web app with multiple instance. To trouble shoot this issue, I suggest that you remote debug the project to find the root cause. For remote debug, you can refer the document below:

[Introduction to Remote Debugging on Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/)